# Trailing newline in file when reading JSON in Pyspark results in empty line

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

When loading JSON data into Spark (v2.4.2) on AWS EMR from S3 using Pyspark, I've observed that a trailing line separator (\n) in the file results in an empty row being created on the end of the Dataframe. Thus, a file with 10,000 lines in it will produce a Dataframe with 10,001 rows, the last of which is empty/all nulls.

The file looks like this:

```
{line of JSON}\n
{line of JSON}\n
...             <-- 9996 similar lines
{line of JSON}\n
{line of JSON}\n
```

There are no newlines in the JSON itself, i.e. I don't need to read the JSON as multi-line. I am reading it with the following Pyspark command:

```
df = spark.read.json('s3://{bucket}/{filename}.json.gz')
df.count()
-> 10001
```

My understanding of this quote from http://jsonlines.org/:

> The last character in the file may be a line separator, and it will be treated the same as if there was no line separator present.

... is that that last empty line should not be considered. Am I missing something? I haven't seen anyone else on SO or elsewhere having this problem, yet it seems very obvious in practice. I don't see an option in the Spark Python API docs for suppressing empty lines, nor have I been able to work around it by trying different line separators and specifying them in the load command.

I have verified that removing the final line separator results in a Dataframe that has the correct number of lines.

Comment: did you try reading via multiline option? ```df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("data.json")```

Comment: I added `multiLine=True` to the `spark.read.json()` command, but when I did it only read a single row. The file is constructed specifically to conform to JSONLines, and to NOT be multi-line, as any line breaks in the JSON are escaped.

Comment: i understand now after re-looking at the sample file ... i don't understand why "\n" is causing an extra row for you ... i made my own sample json and am not having this problem ... have you tried uncompressing the .gz then reading?

Comment: Yes, I have tried loading the same data compressed and uncompressed, with the same results. I had additional issues with line separators before, when I had `\r\n` as the separator... with the default line separator, I was getting double rows, i.e. a 'normal' row, followed by a blank/empty row. I had to either specify the line separator as '\n', or change the file to have `\n` as the line break instead (either worked).

Comment: how/who is generating this json? perhaps they are using windows or some OS not producing valid json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The file I was uploading had an unexpected encoding (UCS-2 LE BOM instead of UTF-8). I should have thought to check it, but didn't. After I switched the encoding to the expected one (UTF-8) the load worked as intended.